# Difference Between SQL Server Management Studio date filter and Excel/PowerBI date filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powerbi, ssms

I have a SQL query which looks like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE Date >='2019'
```

which results in 214.096 rows.

If I copy the results (214.096 rows) into Excel or PowerBI and filter for `Date >= 2022`, I get 11.460 results for 2022 (in both Excel and Power BI).

However if use the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE DATE >= '2022'
```

I get 13.157 rows.

For the other years I get the following results:

**2019**

- Excel/Power BI: 70.091
- SQL: 70.091

  ```
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE DATE >= '2019' AND DATE < '2020'
  ```

**2020**

- Excel/Power BI: 67.645
- SQL : 69.401

  ```
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE DATE >= '2020' AND DATE < '2021'
  ```

**2021**

- Excel/Power BI: 64.902
  SQL : 69.516

  ```
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE DATE >= '2021' AND DATE < '2022'
  ```

**2022**

- Excel/Power BI: 11.460
- SQL : 13.157

  ```
    SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE 
    WHERE DATE >= '2022' AND < '2023'
  ```
- That equals in Excel/PowerBI: 214.096
- In SQL for the query with Date >= '2019': 214.096
- If I sum the different queries for the years: 222.165

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this could be a problem linked to data convertion, try converting your `date` column to date, user `YEAR` function in the condition, that could solve your problem.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, but the result was the same.